# Ruby on Rails database: how to mention foreign key relation by changing app/model/table.rb file how to know they implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, foreign-keys

I am new to RoR. I used "rails generate model ServiceConfigs" command to generate a table. 
so may commands are as below
 rails generate model ServiceConfigs configs:string
 rake db:migrate 
-- can see app/db/service_config.rb created. 
Now edited service_config.rb file to add 2 columns and which has a foreign key relation to service table. So here is code

```
class ServiceConfigs < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service, :dependent => :destroy 

  validates_presence_of :configs
end
```

Now when I login to underline database, and look at the table I don't see foreign key relation in table schema. Whats wrong/more I need to do?

highly appreciate your time and help
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

So a few notes for you as you're getting started here: Firstly, I'd name your model in the singular form, as though you are describing a single instance of it: `ServiceConfig` and in the case where it belongs to a service, you may want to think of a different name all together.

Secondly `validates_presence_of` suggests that you have that field, so firstly, I'd remove the validation until you know that your DB has that column and that the migration worked. You can make sure by looking at your migration file and confirming that the column is being created.

You can define the relationship the "rails way" in your migration too:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

```
create_table :service_configs do |t|
  t.string :configs
  t.references :service
  t.timestamps
end
```

---

**Update**

If you want to rerun a particular migration run:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20100421175455
```

You can take a look in your schema to see what migration you are currently at as well. And you can also take a look at the schema to see what your DB is expected to look like as well.

Comment: hi Joseph, thanks for reply & suggestions. If I miss adding to migration script, and wants to do changes in model/service_config.rb file, how do I do that? I mean for migration script "rake db:migrate" to be run. for changes in model what we need to do? why I can't see it in datatbase?

Comment: thanks it did work. i have another question. if we can do every thing through migration scripts then what is point in creating model file?